# MiniProfiler works on local machine, not on QA

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

I used NuGet to install MiniProfiler and MiniProfiler.MVC3 addon. http://miniprofiler.com/

I've tried everything the site suggests including adding this in the web.config:

```
<handlers>
<add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

However, it still won't show up on the page. In fact, the includes don't seem to be rendering at all. Yes, the MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes() is on my master page.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need insert this and try to debug.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
//    if (Request.IsLocal)
    {
        MiniProfiler.Start();
    } 
}
```